# What is meant by by output photovoltage in this context?

Tags: photodiode

Regarding the photodiode bias circuit below:

[image]

There is this statement about saturation:

> Photodiodes saturate when the output photovoltage approaches the
> reverse bias voltage. Since photodiodes output a current, the
> saturation limit can be adjusted by modifying the reverse bias voltage
> (within specification) or reducing the load resistance.

What is meant by "output photovoltage"? Which node is that?

And if it was using a TIA(with zero bias) would the saturation limit be maximum?

Answer (score 0):

> *What is meant by "output photovoltage"? Which node is that?*

It refers to the voltage across the terminals of the photodiode.

> *And if it was using a TIA(with zero bias) would the saturation limit be maximum?*

If using a TIA with no reverse bias voltage the voltage across the photodiode is zero and, it is a borderline case. However, it will still produce a decent range of photo-currents because it drives into a theoretically zero ohm load (the TIA).

I believe you got the quotes in your question from [Thorlabs](https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Photodetector_Lab.pdf).

Comment: Yes from there I took the quote. In case of TIA like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJa42.png yes the TIA has zero input impedance so it will bring saturation point to a higher level. But what is confusing is, in case of TIA will increasing reverse bias still more increase the saturation limit? Or in case of TIA the reverse bias has no effect on saturation limit?

Comment: @GNZ when using a TIA an increase in the reverse bias voltage has no effect on saturation. It does however lower the self-capacitance of the photodiode and, this is really useful in applications that require nanosecond response times.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the voltage across the load resistance rather than the photodiode?  If the load resistance is zero the voltage across the photodiode is the reverse voltage.

Comment: Is there a schematic in the linked paper that suggests it is?

Comment: @user1850479 Are you talking about the definition of "output photovoltage"?

Comment: Yes, the output voltage would be the voltage across the load, not the photodiode.

Comment: @GNZ if user1850479 is right then it doesn't really indicate that in the linked document.  So, you need to establish whether this is correct or not. For instance, by linking the image in your question with the site where it came from. It maybe that when considering both documents (the one I linked and where you found the image) it makes sense. This only applies to your first question of course.

Comment: Regarding the reverse bias circuit in my question; do you all mean that the "saturation" occurs when the voltage at the anode node becomes equal to the voltage at the cathode node?

Comment: @GNZ I mean that in a TIA the voltage across the PD is zero and this can mark the onset of saturation in some PDs.